# Using Ansible playbook to start mysql

Tags: ansible

### I am trying to install mysql using the following script.

```
- hosts: webservers
  strategy: debug
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: abkari
  tasks:
    - name: "Install Apache, MySQL and PHP5"
      yum: name={{item}} state=present
      with_items:
        - mysql-server
        - python-mysqldb
        - php5-mysql

    - name: "Turn on Apache and MyDQL"
      service: name = {{item}} state=started enabled=yes
      with_items:
        - mysql

    - name: Create a test dabase
      mysql_db: name=testDb
                state=present

    - name: Create a new user
      mysql_user: name=webapp
                  password=mypassword
                  priv=*.*:ALL state=present
```

When i execute the script it just gives me the following output
playbook: sample_script.yml

```
  play #1 (webservers): webservers      TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'webservers']
    hosts (1):
      10.143.219.12
```

When i go and check on 10.143.219.12 machine. It is not installed at all. 
What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of output is given when you execute `ansible-playbook` with `--list-hosts` option.

It is used to list all hosts that will be altered during playbook run and not actually run any tasks on them.

Omit `--list-hosts` flag and try again.

P.S. and you have typo in `service: name = {{item}}` – when you use `key=value` syntax for parameters, you can't use space near `=` – use `name={{item}}`.

Comment: Thank you. But even with that it should have gone ahead with printing debug statements right

Comment: with `--list-hosts` no single task is executed.

Comment: Ok got it. Also final question. If i have to install the packages but it requires a sudo password what changes are required. I have added  become: yes
  become_method: sudo but it gives me the error sudo: a password is required

Comment: Setup passwordless sudo on remote host or use `--ask-become-pass` for `ansible-playbook`. But asking multiple followup questions is discouraged on SO.

Comment: Ok. i have set passwordless ssh login , but still this is the case. Thanks and and i understand.

Comment: "passwordless ssh" and "passwordless sudo" are two different things.